# Checkstyle doesn't like quotient expression for constant

Tags: java, checkstyle, magic-numbers

```
private static final int DEFAULT_SIZE_IN_BYTES = 256 * 1024;

private static final double SPECIAL_RATIO = 4.0 / 3.0;
```

Our Checkstyle is fine with the first constant being established by a product expression, but it complains that both literals in the quotient expression for the second constant are themselves magic numbers. Is there a way to tell Checkstyle to accept a quotient of literals as valid?

Comment: Have you tried opening an issue at https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MagicNumberCheck.java#L109](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/0f58857d73933c7b6b7e62f0c7c16ad7af51556f/src/main/java/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/checks/coding/MagicNumberCheck.java#L109) the following tokens are allowed between the number literals and enclosing constant definition to not be considered as magic numbers:

- ASSIGN (`=`),
- ARRAY_INIT (array initializer),
- EXPR (any expression),
- UNARY_PLUS (`+`),
- UNARY_MINUS (`-`),
- TYPECAST (cast operator),
- ELIST (list of expressions),
- LITERAL_NEW (`new`),
- METHOD_CALL (method call),
- STAR (`*`)

As you see there is no **DIV** (`/`) token on the list and this list is unfortunately unconfigurable.

I've opened [the issue](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues/1113) and [pull request](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/pull/1114) to fix it in next version of Checkstyle.

**EDIT:**

Pull request has been merged and this feature will be released in Checkstyle 6.7.